# Prevent publish all in silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

Silverstripe has the ability for users to publish all pages on a site available at /admin/pages/publishall and the publish all code is in /cms/code/controllers/CMSMain.php

We've had some problems with users accidentally running publish all in production when it should only be run from other environments - How can I disable the publishall functionality?

Comment: Did they "accidentally" also pushed the "confirm" button? Users, right? What version of ss are you running? Since I don't see any hooks for extending that function, or any check of dev envs, you probably can't disable the functionality unless you modify the code (don't do it). It does check for admin permissions tho, so you could just make a new role with almost all permissions set for the other users, just don't give them ADMIN perms and it'll be ok.

Comment: The issue was that an admin user ran publishall in production thinking that they were in dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first approach to fixing this was to create a custom CMSPageController.php in which I would overwrite publishall, and just place a call to parent::publishall($request) inside an if block checking which environment we were in. The problem with this approach was that injecting the custom class created issues with editing pages. Ideally I would have been able to just extend publishall but as Nunser mentioned above, Silverstripe(frustratingly) hasn't included extension hooks in that method.

I ended up creating a custom route to overwrite admin/pages/publishall

so inside mysite/_config/routes.yml

```
'admin/pages/publishall': CustomPublishallController
```

and in mysite/code/controllers/CustomPublishallController.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Controller for providing silverstripes inbuilt publishall functionality with the ability to
 * run in production removed.
 *
 * @package  sitename
 * @subpackage mysite
 */
class CustomPublishallController extends Controller {

    public function index($request){

        $cmsMain = new CMSMain();

        if(ENVIRONMENT_CONSTANT != 'prod'){
            return $cmsMain->publishall($request);
        }
        return Security::permissionFailure($this);
    }

}
```